# AngularJS force array population

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In `AngularJS 1.4.7` i got the following issue, which is that the form does not get populated except when valid

```
<form name="myForm">    
    <input ng-model="FirstName" name="FirstName" ng-minlength="3">
</form>
```

In my controller I got,

```
angular.module('myApp',['$scope',function ($scope){
    $scope.frm={};
}]);
```

What happens is that the $scope.frm{} is populated only when the field is valid I need to populate it in any case

How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: the input `ng-model` is pointing at a variable on the scope called `FirstName`... you don't have that variable, you have `frm`. So you need to change the `ng-model` to `frm.FirstName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
angular.module('myApp',['$scope',function ($scope){
    $scope.frm={};
}]);
```

Above code is not valid. You have to define angular `module` and bind controller to it.

In controller you can use `object.property` for binding `frm` to form.

For example. `$scope.frm.FirstName`.

> What happens is that the $scope.frm{} is populated only when the field
>   is valid I need to populate it in any case

The reason `$scope.frm.FirstName` populate only field is valid because **use of `ng-minlength`**

For using `$scope.frm` in anycase, you can remove `ng-minlength` and check length on form submit.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller("MyCtrl", ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.frm = {};
    $scope.frm.FirstName = '';
    $scope.frm.validateSubmit = function() {
      if ($scope.frm.FirstName.length < 4) {
        snippet.log('please enter atleast three character');
        return false;
      }
      //Do something if data is valid
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<form ng-app="myApp" name="myForm" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input ng-model="frm.FirstName" name="FirstName">
  <button ng-click="frm.validateSubmit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```